# Кроп изображения в админке Django с помощью cropper.js

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-admin

Нужно передавать на сервер обрезанное с помощью JS библиотеки изображение. Как это реализовать?

Есть модель с imageField, в админке есть кнопка для выбора изображений. Как сделать так, чтобы после выбора изображения можно было запустить скрипт, и передать в качестве изображения его уже обрезанную копию?

Comment: Допиливать фронтенд джанго-админки сильно геморно, готовых и рабочих библиотек для этого вроде нет (я себе писал, но в джанге 1.11 всё сломалось), так что, боюсь, в ближайшее время в пределах ruSO вам вряд ли помогут

Comment: @andreymal Все так плохо? Вроде же как то можно с помощью особой технической магии или манкипатчинга переопределить шаблон админки, и дописать нужную логику, или нет?

Comment: Можно-то можно, но сильно геморно)

Comment: @andreymal ладно, спасибо. Покапаю в эту сторону.

Answer (score 0):

пробую вот это, но не встает
https://github.com/ilya-chistyakov/django-sorl-cropping

есть вариант это перепилить для бэки 
https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2017/03/02/how-to-crop-images-in-a-django-application.html

переопределив конкретный шаблон модели 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates